# Nodejs and Zombie for web crawler

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, zombie.js

I use the npm package "zombie" to visit the [website](https://booking.tigerair.com).
Here is my code of nodejs.

```
var Browser = require('zombie');
var url = "https://booking.tigerair.com";
var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(browser.success);
});
```

But I get the result:

```
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
true
```

Though I researched the [official document](http://zombie.js.org/#cookies)
, It didn't illustrate the problem.

Here is my basic info of nodejs.

node version : "v0.12.7"
npm version : "2.11.3"
zombie version : "2.5.x"

Thank you for all your advice.

Comment: Zombie 4.x is tested to work with io.js 1.6 or later. If you need to use Node 0.12 or earlier, consider using Zombie 2.x. Install node 4.0

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I use zombie "2.5.x".